# How to set variable depending on other variable in yaml?

Tags: conditional-statements, yaml

I am writing a yaml where wanted to set onprem or aws url depending on a local variable on the same file.

```
variables:
    env: &urlEnv aws

url: *urlEnv == "aws" ? "http://som aws eurl" : "http:// some other url"
```

The local variable can be changed to either aws or inhouse. Our logic should decide which value should be loaded.

Comment: YAML is a data serialization language. It doesn't provide any form of expressions, control flow, logic or variable interpolation.